# How is it possible to "see" or "read" the ELO character in a file

Tags: php, file, import

I import some file in SQL with php

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
```

for most of the file it work fine but for 2-3 file the

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

dont work... i must use :

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

instead... so the question is... how to "read" the file and detect the line end character and send that to the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE import...

I like to "see" if it /r or /r/n
how do i do that in php ?

so at the end, i have some file with lines ending with /r and some ending with /r/n, i need to read it wich one it is, and send it as a var to the LOAD

Comment: the PHP_EOL is a constant to send it, but i have to read file with different line termination... i need to look at it and read it... is it /r or /r/n ?

Comment: it's not a matter of preprocessing or changing it... i need to read and know what the END OF LINE caracter is... i will live with whatever it is.. i just need to read it properly

Comment: I am NOW writing my function that read the last caracter in ASCII and if it's 10 read the before last one, and if it's 13 the i will know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution....not pretty, but efficient

```
//======================================================================
function EOL_reader($filename) {

    $return = "";

    $loaded_thing = file($filename);
    $first_line = $loaded_thing[0];

    $lenght = strlen($first_line);
    $the_last = $loaded_thing[0][$lenght-1];
    $one_before_last = $loaded_thing[0][$lenght-2];

    if (ord($the_last) == 10) { $return = "\n";}
    if (ord($one_before_last) == 13) { $return = "\r\n"; }

    return $return;

}
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't return anything. I am a bit concerned you spelt length as lenght too